# How do I send an Object to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I can't send text message to kafka from my application but when I try to send an Object (Event) I receive an exception:

> INFO: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: in org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AfterSaveEvent null of org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AfterSaveEvent, headers={id=9068de1b-a1cc-c1b5-463a-107b7be21af4, timestamp=1456754038408}] 1000

```
<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext" producer-properties="producerProperties">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>

        <!-- Kafaka events topic -->
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration
                broker-list="localhost:9092"
                key-class-type="java.lang.String"
                key-encoder="kafkaReflectionEncoder"
                value-encoder="kafkaReflectionEncoder"
                value-class-type="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AfterSaveEvent"
                topic="eventsstream"
                compression-type="none"
        />

    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>

 <bean id="kafkaReflectionEncoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String" />
</bean>
```

any help is welcome...

Comment: what version of kafka are you using?

Comment: What is `kafkaReflectionEncoder`?

Comment: Kafka 0.82 and 0.90... Looks like serializations issue?

Comment: I'm using org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder. Please see the update